# fmod producing unexpected values?

Tags: c++

Im using fmod() in one of my programs, and it is producing unexpected results, can anyone help me with this?

this is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double test = 0.756;

    while (fmod(test, 1) != 0)
    {
        test = test * 10;
        std::cout << test << " " << fmod(test, 1) << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Final Product: " << test;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
7.56 0.56
75.6 0.6
756 1.13687e-13
7560 9.09495e-13
...
Final Product: 7.56e+15
```

Why does `fmod(756, 1) == 1.13687e-13`? Shouldn't `fmod(756, 1) == 0`?

Comment: Nope! Generally speaking, you should never try to get exact results out of floating point calculations.

Comment: @Hurkyl I assumed this was because of floating point precision. Thanks!

Comment: There may be a guarantee about `fmod(756,1)` (I'm not sure on that fine of detail) but I additionally think it's likely that the number printed as `756` is not actually equal  to `756.0`. I bet you'd see a difference if you changed the precision of the printing.

Comment: @Hurkyl Your right, i just stepped through it, and found the value was actually 756.00000000000011. That solves my problem, thanks for the help